# how to stop tomcat in case of configuration loading failure

Tags: java, tomcat, config

i have this error while launching tomcat 
log from catalina.out

```
Unable to load specified config location file:/ .... startup failed:
```

Is there a way to make my java code cath this error and stop my tomcat ?

Comment: how you are starting you tomcat application? if you are starting you tomcat application as a separate process then there is nothing to do with java.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will start up no matter what happens with the applications you expected to deploy. There is no feature to cause Tomcat to fail to start if your application fails to start properly.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly do not want that feature - at least other Tomcat users do not want it. A ServletContainer can host multiple web applications, and I would not use a container that would stop simply because a deployment failed.

If a deployment fails, that particular application is not started but others continue to run. It is up to you to fix the configuration problem and redeploy or manually stop the tomcat.